# Help solving this: $\cos(x)=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Help solving this: $\cos(x)=2$.

Is this possible since the range of $\cos$ is $[-1;1]$?

Comment: For real $x$, no. For complex $x$, yes. I imagined the great detective would be more interested in, say, $L$-functions...

Comment: It's possible if you allow complex arguments for $\cos$. Not for real arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\cos(\mathbb{R})=[-1,1]$, meaning that our argument has to be [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). Three centuries ago, the great [Leonhard Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) discovered that $\cos x=\cosh ix=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2=\dfrac{e^{2ix}+1}{2e^{ix}}$ . By letting $t=e^{ix}$, we have $\dfrac{t^2+1}{2t}=2\iff t^2-4t+1=0\iff t=2\pm\sqrt3\iff e^{ix}=2\pm\sqrt3\iff ix=$ $=\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)\iff x=-i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$. But $\cos$ is an [even function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions), meaning that if $\cos x=y$, then $\cos(-x)=y$ as well, so $x=i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$ is a solution as well. At the same time, $\cos$ is also a [periodic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) with period $T=2\pi$, so, in conclusion, all complex numbers of the form $x=2k\pi$$\pm i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , are solutions to the initial equation, $\cos x=2$.